# How to Sum FormatCurrency() Value?

Tags: excel, vba

SAMPLE: I have sales in two days and I formatted each value per day in Currency

```
Dim firstSales,secondSales as String

firstSales = 1500
secondSales = 1500

Me.firstDaySales.Caption = FormatCurrency(firstSales)
Me.secondDaySales.Caption = FormatCurrency(secondSales)
```

I got the right format for each value per day in caption

```
Me.totalSales.Caption = Val(firstDaySales) + Val(secondDaySales)
```

But when I try to get the total Sum of  `Val(firstDaySales)` and `Val(secondDaySales)` I got the wrong answer **"0"** beacause the value of `Val(firstDaySales)` and `Val(secondDaySales)` become **"?1,500.00"**, it didn't recognize as a number or currency.
How to solve it?

Thank You.

Comment: Not related to your question, but note that ```Dim firstSales,secondSales as String``` actually is ```Dim firstSales As Variant,secondSales as String``` in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the values, not the captions, then format

```vb
Dim firstSales As Double 
Dim secondSales as Double 

firstSales = 1500
secondSales = 1500

Me.firstDaySales.Caption = FormatCurrency(firstSales)
Me.secondDaySales.Caption = FormatCurrency(secondSales)

Me.TotalSales.Caption = FormatCurrency(firstSales + secondSales)
```

Comment: It is the correct method, though, for _amounts_, data type _Currency_ should be used, _Double_ only in special cases, and never _Single_.